# Feature requires API "21" or higher, but still works on lower

Tags: android, performance, android-studio

I used this style:

```
<resources>
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <!-- Primary theme color of the app (sets background color of app bar) -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">#FF9800</item>
    <!-- Background color of buttons in the app -->
    <item name="colorButtonNormal">#FF9800</item>
</style>
```

I copy-pasted this from some tutorial, and the teacher said that "colorButtonNormal" wont work in API lower than 21. I went to developer.android.com to do a research and that was correct. But i started app, and it is fully functional on my Xperia X8 which is API 9, the buttons are truly orange, just like that hex color code. Can someone explain to me what is really happening there. And what really bothers me, is that Android Studio never warned me that I am using features that requires API higher than my minimum selected (which is 9). I used the Analyze->Inspect Code, no warnings about that..
Now I'm confused, is there something i can do, so i can see if i'm using some features that requires higher API than my minimum.

Comment: welcome to android dev world!

Answer (score 0):

Because you declared it as Theme.AppCompat.Light and it will be compatible with older versions of android 
[Read this guide](https://developer.android.com/training/material/compatibility.html#SupportLib)